# Windows7, defragment swap and hibernate file and move them to begin of hdd

Tags: windows-7, performance, optimize, swap-file

I tried find any tool for windows7 that help me with defrag swapspace, and move them to beginning of volume. I have no option to create separate partition for swap only, because I have 4 primary partitions and I don't want change this.

I need this because I want optimize performance for swap. This is heavy used. I know, best idea is shopping and RAM increase :) but I can't. Another idea is ReadyBoost. I did it using SDHC 10class card. Unfortunately this is not enough, then I decided to move and defragment swapfile to start of hard drive. Unfortunately I don't see any tool that can do that.

Removing swap and creating again doesn't work as I want, because this is created in random place. Usualy rather on slow end of disk, rather fast begin :(

Is it any idea which software can manipulate swap like I want?

Comment: Two comments:
1) "but I can't." -> "But I do not want to" since you actually CAN do that.
2) Recreating swap sort of works if you turn swap off. Defrag and only then turn swap back on with a decent minimum size. This creates a continious swap file after all the previously defragmented files. If you do this on the c: volume (where you normally just store the OS) and not on D: (the data volume) then swap will not be in a bad spot.

Comment: Windows doesn't let you choose the exact place where the paging/hibernation files will be stored. As a workaround, you could: 1. Disable hibernation and the paging file 2. Restart Windows to apply the changes. 3. Shrink the partition by leaving enough free space just for the paging and hibernation files. 4. Defragment the partition, and enable both hibernation and the paging file. 5. Restart Windows. 6. Extend the partition to its original size.

Comment: I know I can disable, defragment and again enable swap and hiber. Unfortunately that files often is located by windows too far from partition begin, then I'm trying find some tools that move swap to specified area. About 'but I can't", this is not my personal comp, but my employer. There are often strange procedures, then I really can't increase RAM. I hope this will change soon :) But thank you for helpfull opinions. At now I'm testing Paragon Total Defrag with 30 days trial. I see, this reboot my computer and try move swap/hiber. Maybe this help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Paragon Total Defrag could partially help. Unfortunately this isn't free software, but has 30 days for testing. Another bad news is, there is no way to setup this program for storing swap/hibernation files in specified place. Program decides for us where to place them.

Comment: I used two different software. MyDefrag with script that moves the most of data to end of disk (this is in examples). Works very slow. Then Paragon Total Defrag. It isn't good software, very often hangs, but works. It moved system files to disk beginning. At last I run MyDefrag again with standard 'systemdisk' sorting option. This took a lot of time but works. Not perfectly, but better that way than nothing.